# WebAPI: DelegatingHandler and ApiController on the same thread?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

In a WebAPI Self-Host application, will SendAsync() method of DelegatingHandler and any method of ApiController always execute on the same thread?

Is it safe to use [ThreadStatic] variable to pass RequestId from SessionHandler to TestController ?

Example:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Run()
    {
        LogManager.GetLogger("Controller").InfoFormat("Thread id: {0} ", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return "Bar";
    }
}

public class SessionHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        LogManager.GetLogger("SessionHandler").InfoFormat("Thread id: {0} ", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> In a WebAPI Self-Host application, will SendAsync() method of DelegatingHandler and any method of ApiController always execute on the same thread?
>
> Is it safe to use [ThreadStatic] variable to pass RequestId from SessionHandler to TestController ?

No, and no. `async` on WebAPI returns the thread to the runtime, so any asynchrony in the pipeline (controller actions, filters, etc) may resume on another thread.